# Cassandra Database Performance and Default GUID

Tags: nosql, cassandra, database-performance

I've read in the Cassandra docs that it's recommended that you stay with the random generated GUI for IDs to prevent hotspots instead of implementing my own IDs for each document. From what I know it is much slower ([see this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/scode/scaling-with-apache-cassandra)). How Cassandra can help me achieve very high WRITE performance while still following this guideline?

Comment: Everything I've read about Cassandra performance says that putting the commit log on its own fast disk is the best thing, i.e. commit log flushes are the gating factor for writes.  Are you saying that the presentation said guid generation was slow?

Comment: See also http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/cluster_architecture/partitioning. There shouldn't normally be much speed difference (the RandomPartitioner has to MD5 hash your row key, that's all) - are your row keys very large? What write performance are you seeing, and what are you aiming for?

Comment: MY row keys are not large,  expect about 5000 writes / sec

Answer (score 1):

PlayOrm uses it's own generater that keeps the ids small for cassandra.  The important thing is that your generator be random, that is all, so it provides a good distribution of keys.  We are doing 10,000 writes / second with PlayOrm and cassandra ourselves and that is while stuff is being indexed so we can query using PlayOrm Scalable SQL.